# Why List partition works while span does not

Tags: scala

I have this List oX of (Char, Int) pars (it contains pairs with only unique Char values)

```
List(( ,3), (d,1), (e,3), (h,3), (i,1) , (l,3), (o,2), (r,2), (t,1), (w,1))
```

I need to partition this list into 2 - one that contains any pair that has 'd' Char and another is the rest.

So I tried partition and span but found that span does not work as expected. Here are the results (copied from scala worksheet)

```
 val myPartition = oX.partition(e => e._1 == 'd') > myPartition  : (List[(Char, Int)], List[(Char, Int)]) = (List((d,1)),List(( ,3), (e,3), (h,3), (i,1), (l,3), (o,2), (r,2), (t,1), (w,1)))

  val mySpan = oX.span(e => e._1 == 'd') > mySpan  : (List[(Char, Int)], List[(Char, Int)]) = (List(),List(( ,3), (d,1), (e,3), (h,3), (i,1), (l,3), (o,2), (r,2), (t,1), (w,1)))
```

I am puzzled why given same predicate functino partition gives me expected result while span gives me empty List as first list and copy of original as second list

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.0/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.List) of `span`: "Returns the longest prefix of the list whose elements all satisfy the given predicate, and the rest of the list."

So here `span` gives you the expected result: since the first tuple in your list doesn't have the character `d`, the longest prefix of the list where each tuple has the character `d` is indeed the empty list.